# In ADF Mobile, How to change the button text when the button is clicked?

Tags: button, oracle-adf-mobile

First, in the page, the Button text is set to "Edit" and show.

When I clicked the "Edit" button, then the Button text will change to "Done", meanwhile, it will do a action to render some checkBoxs on the page.

After I pick some checkBox, and click the "Done" button, it will do another action.

I don't know how to do it in ADF Mobile. Can we just using this one button to do all these?

Thanks!

---

I chose to use two button, here is my code:

```
  <amx:facet name="secondary">
  <amx:commandButton id="cb2" text="#{viewcontrollerBundle.EDIT}" rendered="#{viewScope.editMode == ''}">
    <amx:setPropertyListener id="spl1" from="EditMode" to="#{viewScope.editMode}" type="action"/>
  </amx:commandButton>
  <amx:commandButton id="cb3" text="#{viewcontrollerBundle.DONE}" rendered="#{viewScope.editMode == 'EditMode'}">
    <amx:actionListener id="al1" binding="#{bindings.removeFromImageList.execute}"/>
    <amx:setPropertyListener id="spl2" from="" to="#{viewScope.editMode}" type="action"/>
  </amx:commandButton>
</amx:facet>
```

This code can show the DONE button when click the edit button. And in my test page, it works.
But when I put them into my project page, it cannot show the DONE button immediately. I should turn to the previous page, and go back to the page again, then the DONE button will show.
Do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the same button. You can set the value of text field for the button as a property of a bean. And in the action listener which is a function in the same bean, you can do different actions based on the text.

AMX Page will look something like

```
<amx:commandButton text="{applicationScope.myBean.buttonText}" id="cb3" styleClass="actions-button" actionListener="#{applicationScope.myBean.myListener}"></amx:commandButton>
```

The bean should look something like

```
public class Class1 {
    private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public Class1() {
        super();
    }

    private String textButton;

    public void myListener(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (textButton.equals("Edit")) {
            //DO THE ACTION WHICH NEEDS TO BE DONE FOR EDIT BUTTON
            setTextButton("Done");
        } else if (textButton.equals("Done")) {
            //DO THE ACTION FOR DONE BUTTON
        }
    }

    public void setTextButton(String textButton) {
        String oldTextButton = this.textButton;
        this.textButton = textButton;
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("textButton", oldTextButton, textButton);
    }

    public String getTextButton() {
        return textButton;
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener l) {
        propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(l);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener l) {
        propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: Arun, thanks for your reply. In my code, I try to use two button to do it. Use the amx:setPropertyListener to do it.

Comment: I updated my question, would you please have a look?

Comment: Can you try removing the secondary facet and simply putting the button? ANd what exactly changed when moving from test page to actual project? Your code should work. I dont see any issues. Also instead of using a simple viewScope variable, try putting the property into a bean. And in the setter of that property add the propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange() as I have done in my previous code snippet. Only thing that could go wrong is the propertyChange event not firing properly.

Comment: Hi Arun, I have tried as you said to remove the secondary facet and just put the button on the page. But the button still cannot change when clicking. Then I also try to remove the fragment in the page, this time, the button can change automatically. Do you face this issue? I think this is caused by the fragment. The fragment .amxf file needs the attribute "viewScope.editMode", which is used to control the rendering of the selectBooleanCheckBox when the viewScope.editMode equals "EditMode".

Comment: I was not aware you were using fragments. I think there was some bug related to this. Are you sure you are on the latest version available?